# Facebook Messenger Bot Daily Push Notification, How?

Tags: facebook, messenger

In cnn fb messenger bot if i write subscribe they show a message like "Got it. I’ll send you top stories every day." and then they daily send me top stories at fixed time. How they do it? I created an fb bot for my site without this but i can't understand how i add this. can anyone tell me basic instruction for this?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just respond to messages

Comment: Now i can not add a method like cnn meesenger bot (daily top stories at fixed time)? and my code created with php curl

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: like following [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657366/messenger-bot-in-php-no-response-back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657366/messenger-bot-in-php-no-response-back) it's work in my site.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is simple. When you send "subscribe" to the bot, the bot server would add a record according to the `sender_id` to their database or memory , then the bot server could set a timer to distribute the news messages to **those** `sender_id` who have subscribed for the news.

Comment: Thanks brother for this. Can you show me a basic code how it's work by php?

Comment: don't know which part you want. For the bot receiver and sender there are some sample codes written in php, you can search and reach them through internet. For the daily notification, you can use `crontab` to schedule a task, select the sender_id in your database and send the message to the users.

Comment: Hi Thanks brother for crontab information.I am working to following link [https://gist.github.com/visitdigital/58c71acb123870d1ac2ec714d7536587](https://gist.github.com/visitdigital/58c71acb123870d1ac2ec714d7536587). From this link, you will show "The message you want to return" [line number 30]. For example, how i send daily this message automatic to user like cnn by php.