# Connecting WORKPLACE by facebook with ZAPIER webhook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, zapier, facebook-workplace

I'm trying to create a integration on WORKPLACE by facebook and zapier.

To do that create a custom integration then open zapier e select the trigger CATCH A HOOK, this trigger give me a URL. I am using this URL in the webhook section of WORKPLACE custom integration.

When a do that zapier process as the testing was ok. But FACEBOOK WORKPLACE did not and give me a error in configure webhook signature or token.

Does anyone have done this integration!?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 8 months old and you probably used a different solution, but I ran into the same problem this week and wanted to answer this for anyone else who comes along later.

According to [Facebook's webhook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started) (which the Workplace docs point to), Facebook first sends a verification request in the form of a challenge integer, which you need to catch and return. Only after you've passed verification does the webhook actually subscribe and work.

I checked with Zapier support and they don't support these types of requests.

My solution was to write my own script that I point Facebook's webhook to, pass the verification challenge, and then intercept the payload, grab the information I needed out of it, and pass that on to Zapier with my own cURL POST.

I used PHP and this got me past Facebook's verification request:

```
<?php
$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if ($verify_token === 'YOUR_VERIFICATION_TOKEN') {
  echo $challenge;
}
?>
```

For passing the payload on to Zapier, it depends on what you need to pass and what you are trying to do. I recommend checking out [Zapier's Webhook docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609549/facebook-chat-bot-php-webhook-sending-multiple-replies#36616229).